# How to build component to play videos using angular 4

Tags: angular, video, video-streaming, angular-components

I have created Rest webservices to get list of Contents using spring-boot. Content has a field for videoURL of Content. On frontend I'm using angular4. Now I want to build a component to show this videoURL and play that video. What is the best way to build this component.